# How to increment local variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, variable, function, arithmetic

Data

```
1
\begin{document}
3
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash

function getStart {
        local START="$(awk '/begin\{document\}/{ print NR; exit }' data.tex)"
        echo $START
}

START2=$(getStart)
echo $START2
```

which returns `2` but I want `3`. 
I change unsuccessfully the end by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348941/54964) about *How can I add numbers in a bash script*:

```
START2=$((getStart+1))
```

How can you increment a local variable in Bash script?

Comment: I'm getting 2, not 1, from the code.

Comment: Sorry my mistake!

Comment: OFF: why `awk`? `sed -n '/begin{document}/{=;q}' data.text` much shorter…

Comment: @Costas Yes, you are right! I have had today a bad day in thinking too complicated. Thinking now the thing here for open intervals: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229060/16920 Can you explain `}/{=;q}` this in an answer/comment, please?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm getting `2` from your code. Nevertheless, you can use the same technique for any variable or number:

```
local start=1
(( start++ ))
```

or

```
(( ++start ))
```

or

```
(( start += 1 ))
```

or

```
(( start = start + 1 ))
```

or just

```
local start=1
echo $(( start + 1 ))
```

etc.

Comment: This may also help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
START2=$(( `getStart` + 1 ));
```

The `$(( ))` tells bash that it is to perform an arithmetic operation, while the backticks tells bash to evaluate the containing expression, be it an user-defined function or a call to an external program, and return the contents of stdout.

Answer (score 1):

This is the safe bet

```
(( start = start + 1 ))
```

If the resulting value is non zero, then setting exit on error will stop Your script

```
set -e
start=0
(( start++ ))
echo You will never get here
```