# Error [: -lt: unary operator expected in shell script Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, test

I get error  **[: -lt: unary operator expected** after run below script, anyone can share ideas?

```
temp=0
while [ $temp -lt 25 ]
do
    sleep 1
        echo "running.."

   if [ $temp -eq 5 ]
   then
         top -bc -d 5 -n 1|sed -n '7,8p'|awk '{print $1,$9}'>>out.txt
         temp=`expr $temp +1`
         break
   elif [ $temp -eq 20 ]
   then
         top -bc -d 5 -n 1|sed -n '7,8p'|awk '{print $1,$9}'>>out.txt
         temp=`expr $temp +1`
   else
    temp=`expr $temp +1`
   fi
done
```

Comment: Do you also get errors from `expr`?

Comment: no error shown on expr

Comment: [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: Next time please tell us ALL the error messages you get. Not just the last one of a set. You would also have got `expr: syntax error`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing all the `+1`s after the `expr`s to `+ 1`.

Without the space `expr` will return an error and `$temp` will be empty.  If `$temp` is empty, then the `-lt` will be comparing a blank space to a number, which is why the error appears.  Here's a one liner that reproduces the problem:

```
t=0;t=`expr $t +1`;[ $t -lt 25 ]
```

Output (to STDERR):

```
expr: syntax error
bash: [: -lt: unary operator expected
```

Better yet, change all code that uses the external util `expr` to use the shell's own internal arithmetic expansion.  So code like this:

```
temp=`expr $temp +1`
```

...should be changed to:

```
temp=$(($temp + 1))
```

Or, [in `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229050/165517), that whole line can be substituted with just:

```
((temp++))
```